# a tag in a php while loop opens some details in a new window

Tags: php

I got some rows contains a tag (item name) from while loop, I want if I clicked on one of them a new page appears and that page contains some details about the item which I clicked on(without JavaScript).

I used on-click and could open the new page and get some details, but how to relate it to the clicked item.

Code:

```
while($package_fetch = $package_query->fetch_array()){
    $package_td[] = "
    <tr>
        <td>".$package_fetch["package_no"]."</td>
        <td><a href='../reports/r_package.php?hello=true' target='framename'>".$package_fetch["package_name"]."</a></td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with some code, please. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think you can use Item Id in the loop to relate the item, but if you can provide your code may be we can give you better suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the attribue is target and the value is _blank

```
<a href='#' target='_blank'>Page</a>
```

that will open the page in a new window

Comment: Please refer this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score -2):

I think you are mixing things.
Your question seems to be related to html rather than to the server side language you do the loop with.
In addition, it seems you are confusing JavaScript with Java.
Nevertheless, it seems you're looking for the "target" attribute in an anchor element.

Comment: Its seems more like a comment then a answer.